Need to make 380V and 415V 3-phase motors work with 480V 3-phase power supply. Will a 480V->400V autotransformer cut it?
I will have multiple 415V and 380V motors to power with a 480V/3-phase supply due to an international supply chain and tight budget. I would like to know if the solution to my issue is as simple as connecting them all to the secondary of a 480V->400V autotransformer. Not sure yet what power rating. Still waiting for numbers. This 10kVA unit may turn out to be enough.
I want an autotransformer because I can get them cheaper than isolation transformers. I want to know if I am taking a serious risk in my application by opting out of galvanic isolation with this design choice. I don't see why since the step-down is relatively tiny.
Please let me know if there is something I am failing to consider. Considerations for VFD's, or having 10+ motors directly connected to one 400V/3-phase supply, etc.
Thank you.

So long as you keep the neutral and phases all connected correctly it should be fine. You'll just need to make sure the three-phase transformer is correctly rated and suitably boxed and protected/fused.
One of my old fart stories, as a youth I was given a 110v valve communication receiver a long time ago for here in the UK and whoever used it before used a 240v>110v autotransformer, which was fed using a plug that was made to fit into a light socket. The only problem was it had a live chassis so it was 50/50 whether the chassis was actually connected to neutral (as it should have been if on a normal plug and slightly less dangerous) or live. I learnt the best way there is, by experience, why it was dangerous and swapped it for an isolating transformer. I suspect both the plug and the live chassis are things of the past now, hopefully.

I'll keep safety in front, thank you. Would you prescribe installing fuses before the autotransformer or after the autotransformer? Not sure yet if a VFD will be connected here or if it will just be the motor.

An autotransformer is the cheaper option, isolation is not necessary in that voltage step, and you will save money and space.
Be aware that direct starter motors can rise up to 6..8 times rated current during starting cycle, so the size should be increased if necessary. In case multiple motors, it is advisable to make a starting sequence with delay from one to another motor, just to avoid all starting at the same time.
About VDF, check the drives you are going to use. Some drives can be supplied from 380 to 500 V, in that case you can skip the autotransformer and feed directly with 480 V. Be careful to select the motor´s plate voltage in the motor parameters, that way the drive will not output over that voltage limit. Some additional stress will be forced in the cables and the motor, because switching pulses will have proportionally higher voltage than 400 V grid.
If your drives cannot work at 500 V, then you need to feed with the autotransformers. Low power VDF normally uses a rectifier and capacitors to feed DC to the output bridge, so you will have their typical harmonics. The autotransformer will have to live with vibrations and overheating, maybe saturation because the harmonics. One option is to use filters to mitigate the harmonics, maybe mandatory because of rules in your area; other option is to over size the autotransformer.

Excellent insight, thank you. Starting the motors one at a time is a must, understood. Happy to hear I can subtract motors with VFD's taking 380V-500V from my autotransformer sizing calculation. Will be sure to set the VFD's correctly, yes. Fingers crossed there is no motor that will see both a VFD and an autotransformer because it sounds like the two will wear each other out faster. Thanks again.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Voltage reduction transformer.
Talk to your local transformer winding companies. With an autotransformer or the arrangement shown in Figure 1 the transformer is passing the full current through the secondary but at only 1/6 of the voltage so the transformer's kVA rating would only need to be 1/6 of your full load rating. In effect, the transformer is only handling the difference - not the full power.

simulate this circuit
Figure 2. Auto-transformer version.
For the auto-transformer version the top 80 V of the winding needs to be rated for the 400 V current. The remainder of the "primary" only needs to be rated for 1/6 of the current.
Either way, you get a lighter, smaller and cheaper transformer.
Warning: don't base your design on the word of random strangers on the Internet. Again, talk to your supplier and make sure that this will work with motors and that there aren't some funny effects with harmonics, etc.

Pleasantly surprised to hear this, and I've checked it against another source. Small current though common winding and copper savings, excellent. Will read the datasheets closely to size correctly. Thank you so much.
